# on the go and on the way

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand that "on the go" means to be active and that it can also mean "while traveling". Is it right to say "I'm on the go. I'll be there in 10 minutes" or should I stick to "I'm on the way. I'll be there in 10 minutes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

"Be on the go" is an informal phrase meaning "be very active or busy", when applied to a person.

> I've been on the go all morning, and this my first chance to put my feet up.

The sense of "while travelling" is used slightly differently, typically at the end of a sentence

> I will eat on the go.

This is adverbial. It describes the manner or location of eating.  It doesn't describe the person.

So in your example, it doesn't mean "be travelling".  You should stick to "on the way".

Comment: This is the link to the dictionary I referred https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-go
I am confused now as it shows it can mean "while traveling"

Comment: Perhaps, I've tagged my answer now

Comment: Interesting: Collins says that the "while travelling" meaning is valid only in AmE, and the Cambridge dictionary says it's only valid in BrE. The "while travelling". I wouldn't be surprised if this meaning is related the "USB OTG" connection mechanism, which was launched in 2001.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=while+on+the+go+%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cwhile+on+the+go+%3Aeng_uk_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-fiction-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: I think this edit will have clarifed the difference.